# DHCP Trouble; getting APIPA addresses

Tags: networking, dhcp, netgear

I am having trouble with the DHCP Client. I am using a Netgear fvs336gv2 firewall. I recently upgraded to the new firmware and did a factory default reset and reconfigured all the vpn tunnels and LAN. Now the DHCP will work for about 2 days then will stop and APIPA will take over and I get 169..... addresses for the local IP's. When everyone in the office applies a static IP address we can access the internet just fine but DHCP will not work unless we restart the firewall.

Solutions I have tried and were UNSUCCESSFUL:

1. ipconfig / release  /renew
2. uninstalled the network adapter and restarted computer
3. Called ISP and discovered it is not the router it is the firewall causing the problem.
4. Disabled IPv6
5. Tried to set the network address myself

Anyone have anymore ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that the DHCP ip address pool is large enough?

Comment: Yes it is plenty large enough we only have 7 computers and our range is .100-.180

Comment: You should personally check the leases to make sure that it's not doing something silly, like assigning new IPs every hour and not releasing the old ones, thus using up all the leases. Simply "knowing" that it's OK because the design should be good doesn't mean that you didn't make a mistake when implementing, or that the device doesn't have some sort of implementation bug. Have you personally confirmed that there are still leases to give when the problem is happening?

Comment: No I haven't. How would I do that? Set the lease for only an hour?

Comment: DON'T DO THAT - that was the specific example of "doing something silly." The GUI probably has the existing DHCP leases, right? Look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you've already investigated, and confirmed that you're not running out of leases to give.

I'd contact the vendor and open a ticket. I'd also be investigating any logging capabilities offered on that piece of hardware - can you enable verbose logging and send it to a syslog server? If so, do that too. According to the manual, [it does](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/FVS336GV2/FVS336Gv2_CLI_20Mar2014.pdf).

I'd also consider reverting the firmware : did you apply the one to fix or a bug that affected you or apply a security fix? If not, then roll back. The new one could be buggy.

Comment: I have tried to use the dhcp log, but each time I click on it the internet in the office shuts down for about two minutes. Rolling back has been an option, however the UI on each version is completely different and for some reason the back ups do not carry over and we have to start from scratch. So we are trying to avoid doing that again, but it is still an option.

Comment: This device might be bad. Before you upgraded the firmware, did it lock up when viewing the logs? If so, it's a bad (or unsuitable) product or a bad unit. If it's only doing it now, that's more evidence that the firmware is buggy.

Comment: It did not lock up with the old version of firmware. It probably is buggy. It is working right now, if it breaks again in about two days I'll try and roll back to the old firmware. Thanks for the answers everyone.